# Urn probability ~ at least a color is not taken

Tags: probability

An urn contains 30 red balls, 22 white balls and 26 blue balls. We take randomly, without replacement, 15 balls. Which is the probability that at least a color isn't taken?

I don't know how to do this problem, i just know that I want to know
$P($"15 red and white balls$") + P("$15 red and blue balls$") + P("$15 blue and white bals$") + P("$15 blue balls$") + P("$15 red balls$") + P("$15 white balls$")$ but don't know how to start it.

Comment: "*... don't take at least a color*" You always take at least one color. The question is unclear. Or do you mean that at least one color is not taken?

Comment: @callculus He probably means that at least one color is not part of the draw

Comment: @callculus I mean that at least a color isn't taken.

Comment: In English there's a distinction between "a" and "one" that isn't made in many other languages that use articles (e.g. in German both are represented by "ein(e)", in French by "un(e)"). In English, when the aspect of counting is the main focus, "one" is used rather than "a"; this is the case in particular after modifiers such as "at least", "at most", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us define $A$ as “no red balls”, $B$ as “no white balls”, and $C$ as “no blue balls”.

$$
\begin{aligned}
P({A}\cup{B}\cup{C})&=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P({A}\cap{B})-P({A}\cap{C})-P({B}\cap{C})+P({A}\cap{B}\cap{C})\\
&=\frac{\binom{48}{15}+\binom{56}{15}+\binom{52}{15}-\binom{26}{15}-\binom{22}{15}-\binom{30}{15}+0}{\binom{78}{15}}
\end{aligned}
$$

You may want to read about the principle of inclusion - exclusion (i hope i remember the name correctly)